# A tool to replace code drilling with using React Context

Tags: react

My React.js code has many instances of prop drilling, whereby a piece of state is passed as a prop through many levels of component hierarchy. I am looking for a tool to help me replace passing a specific prop down the hierarchy with using React Context. `react-codemod` does not seem to have a transform for this task. Is there a tool that can help me with this task?